# Как сделать, чтобы меню было слева, а логотип - на той же линии, но справа?

Tags: html, css

[image: Логотип]

```html
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
<ul>
  <li>Пункт1</li>
  <li>Пункт2</li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=L"></li>
</ul>
```

Надо, чтобы отступ у логотипа был в 15 пикселей от правого края страницы, а меню - отступ 20 пикселей от левого. Между меню и логотипом много свободного места.

Comment: вы покажите конкретный пример, скриншот ...что в результате должно получится

Comment: Добавила картинку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul {
  height: 50px;
}

ul li {
  height: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 1;
}

ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

ul li:not(:last-child){
  padding-top: 18px;
}

ul li:last-child {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт1</li>
  <li>Пункт2</li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=L"></li>
</ul>
```

Если есть вопросы, задавайте.

Comment: Спасибо, очень просто и работает!

Answer (score 1):

Что касается выравнивания элементов по оси `X или Y` с этим прекрасно справляется `flex`. Меньше стилей и получаем нужный результат. Что касается разброс элементов по противоположным сторонам, то за это отвечает `justify-content: space-between;`.
При этом правила `flex` учитывают `margin && padding` как родительских элементов так и дочерних...

Так же можно использовать `grid-Ы`.   ***`grid-Ы даже круче flex`***

```css
body {
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

body * {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.logo-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <menu>
    <li>Пункт1</li>
    <li>Пункт2</li>
  </menu>
  <div class="logo-wrap">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=L" />
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Не то - надо, чтобы отступ у логотипа был в 15 пикселей от правого края страницы, а меню - отступ 20 от левого. Между меню и логотипом много свободного места.

Comment: @ЛисаАлиса, это пример как выровнять в одну линию.... Я и не собирался, верстать за вас точь-в-точь как вам именно надо.... Это ресурс, для обмена опытом , а не бесплатный фриланс клуб....

Comment: Извините, если не так выразилась, я просто хотела объяснить, почему это не является решением проблемы. Мне надо не чтобы блоки шли подряд, а чтобы между текстом и логотипом было много места. Я это решила padding-left: 400px; но это дурной способ, поэтому спросила у знающих людей.

Comment: @ЛисаАлиса, Если хочется получить хороший и внятный ответ, то и вопрос должен быть хорошим и внятным..))  В первой редакции вопроса не было той информации, которая должна была быть....

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
    margin: 0 15px 0 20px;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li:last-child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт1</li>
  <li>Пункт2</li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=L"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Почти, только у Вас логотип съехал вниз, а надо - на одной линии. Я это решила padding-left: 400px; Но мне такое решение не нравится.

Comment: Поднимите её... Один с вариантов - отрицательный margin

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `justify-content: space-between`, чтобы между текстом и логотипом было много места.

```css
div.test {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 20px 0 15px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт1</li>
      <li>Пункт2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=L">
</div>
```